# Does NpgSql implicitly rollback a transaction that is open within a connection that is disposed

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, .net-core, npgsql

I've got a question about behaviour of NpgSql connections and transactions.

If I have an open connection that has had a transaction started on it through "BeginTransactionAsync", and I then later run some commands but the connection gets disposed (in the specific case I'm looking at because an exception is thrown inside an await using block - but that shouldn't matter?) - does NpgSql rollback the in progress transaction, and if not, what does happen postgres side?

I am reviewing code of ours that appears to be relying on this behaviour but has been in production with load for some time that hasn't shown problems with this - but I just want to check to be 100% sure of the behaviour.

The code follows this kind of pattern (commercial code, so this is pseudo code that just shows the general shape of what is being done):

```
Task ExampleOperationAsync(NpgsqlDataSource dataSource, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  await using var con = dataSource.OpenConnectionAsync();

  var transaction = await Connection.BeginTransactionAsync(
    IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted, cancellationToken
  );

  // .. do some queries/updates ..

  // exception thrown 
  throw new InvalidOperationException("Unexpected logic problem");

  // commit transaction (except this is never thrown)
  await transaction.CommitAsync();

  // con goes 'out-of-scope' and is disposed - what happens to the transaction?
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: The connection uses ADO.NET protocol.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-overview

Comment: Is the transaction object inside a `using`? Please show relevant code.

Comment: @Charlieface Added an example - yes, transaction (and pooled connection) are created/opened inside an await using block (mentioned in the original post text, but clarified in the example).

Comment: @jdweng what does the 'ADO.NET protocol' mean? That link is just a generic overview of ADO.NET, can you be more specific please?

Comment: You have a driver that is used to make a connection to the database.  The interfaces are standard like oledb, and odbc.

Comment: @jdweng There is no such thing as ADO.Net protocol. ADO.Net is a set of .NET libraries that have objects that inherit from `DbConnection` and `DbCommand` etc

Comment: @Charlieface : You want to call it an interface instead of a protocol?  Standard interfaces are OLEDB, and ODBC.  ADO.NET is another standard.

Answer (score 1):

**No, your current code is not correct, and the transaction will not be cleaned up properly.**

You need a `using` for the transaction object also. If not, then the transaction will only get cleaned up when the physical connection closes. And because of connection pooling, that may not happen for some time.

You should also use `cancellationToken` for opening the connection.

```cs
Task ExampleOperationAsync(NpgsqlDataSource dataSource, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  await using var con = dataSource.OpenConnectionAsync(cancellationToken);

  await using var transaction = await Connection.BeginTransactionAsync(
    IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted, cancellationToken
  );

  // .. do some queries/updates ..

  // exception thrown 
  throw new InvalidOperationException("Unexpected logic problem");

  // commit transaction (except this is never thrown)
  await transaction.CommitAsync();

  // con and transaction goes 'out-of-scope' and are disposed
}
```

Disposal is [clearly documented](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/api/Npgsql.NpgsqlTransaction.html#Npgsql_NpgsqlTransaction_Dispose_System_Boolean_) in a number of places to automatically rollback if the transaction has not been committed yet.

Having said that, opening a transaction from the client requires an extra round-trip, compared to just doing it from a server-side procedure. So it may be beneficial to do that instead.

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface for your answer. Do you have any references on any of this, either code or docs would be good? I agree that makes sense but I do find it strange we've never seen any problems incurred by this in production and under load.

Comment: How often is an error happening? And how much difference does it make if the transaction is left open until the pooling timeout (or the physical connection is resued)? I linked some docs already, not sure what else you want.

Comment: The doc you linked to does indicate that the transaction is rolled back if its disposed, but do you have a link that describes/defines the behaviour of just disposing the connection (and not touching the transaction)?

Comment: No, but connection pooling itself is documented in many places, and as soon as you use that (which is the default) then the physical connection will not be closed until the timeout or it gets reset and reused, therefore no rollback will happen